# How can array be sorted while the method can only pass value?

Tags: java, methods

Since have is value passing when using a method, how come the Array.sort() can change the the original array variable?

I searched everywhere when found out creating a swap(int a, int b) can't change the original value of the variable. Now I am confused while the sort() method can change the array variable.

Comment: A variable that 'contains' an array is a reference to the array in the RAM. So if you pass primitives like int or long, their values are copies. If you pass the reference to the array, that reference (address value) will also be a copy, but it will point to the original array.

Comment: The value is a reference. You can use the value (reference), to affect the referent (the array).

Answer (score 1):

> *"... how come the Array.sort() can change the the original array variable? ..."*

Any *data-type* declared as an *array*, whether *[primitive](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)* or *[Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objects.html)*, is considered an *[Object](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html)* itself.

In otherwords, even if the data-type is *int*, *double*, etc., the  variable containing the *array* is considered a *Reference* type.

Thus, it's similar to passing a typical *Object* to another method, and changing a value from within the method.

```java
static class ABC { String s = ""; }
static void mutate(ABC abc) {
    abc.s = "123";
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ABC abc = new ABC();
    mutate(abc);
    System.out.println("abc.s = " + abc.s);
}
```

Output

```
abc.s = 123
```

Answer (score 1):

This is swap (which does not work):

```
public void swap(int a, int b) {
  int x = a;
  a = b;
  b = x;
}
```

This is a hypothetical 'swap first 2 in an array':

```
public void swap(int[] arr) {
  int x = arr[0];
  arr[0] = arr[1];
  arr[1] = x;
}
```

That one **does work**.

In java, **everything** is a reference, except primitives. That's just java speak for pointer. This:

```
String x = "hello";
```

is often explained as 'x is now "hello"'. **This is incorrect**.

`String x;` means: "This is a page in an address book. It can hold addresses. Not houses - there obviously isn't room to actually pour concrete all over a.. page in an address book! There's just room for an address, that's all we got. The page is restricted: It is slightly magical in that it simply refuses to hold an address at all, unless it is an address that leads to a house that is of the 'String' style of houses. But, it *can* be entirely blank (no address at all)."

The trick is, java does indeed copy parameters, but when it's about a reference (And remember, **everything** is a reference, except primitives - the hardcoded list of `int`, `long`, `short`, `byte`, `double`, `float`, `boolean`, and `char`). Even arrays of primitives and Strings are references.

So, when you do:

```
int[] x = new int[] {1, 2};
swap(x);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x)); // prints 2, 1! The swap worked!
```

That's because:

- `new int[] {1, 2};` builds a new house.
- `int [] x = ...` takes the **address** of that newly built house and writes on a piece of paper called `x`. x isn't the house. It's just an address to the house.
- `swap(x)` grabs a second piece of paper and *copies the address onto it*_. It's a copy. Of the address, not the house. It then hands that second copy to the method (and that method will rip it up when it is done; it is not returned and therefore whatever modifications the method makes **to that piece of paper** has no bearing on what the piece of paper that the caller owns has written on it.
- `arr[0]` **dereferences** - derefencing is java-ese for 'put on your shoes, go out the door, walk over to the address written on this piece of paper you are dereferencing, knock on the door, and yell something'. `[0]` means: "TELL ME WHAT YOUR #0 ITEM IS PLEASE!". The other common dereference operation is the dot. `list.add("foo")` is not 'adding a string to list'. It's taking the 'list' address, walking over to the street and house number that your piece of paper lists, and then yelling at the house: "ADD "foo" PLEASE!".

Imagine this method:

```
public void swap(int[] arr) {
  arr = new int[] {arr[1], arr[0]};
}
```

That one **does not work**. That's because that one:

- Builds a new house.
- Then takes its `arr` piece of paper and takes an eraser to it so that it is blank, then writes the address of this newly built house on it.
- Then the method ends, and all pieces of paper go into the bin.

Hence why that does not work. `=` wipes out the paper and writes a different address on. `.` and `[]` follow the address.

Imagine you have an address book. I make a copy of it. If I go and edit an address in my copy that has no bearing on your address book.

However, if I go to one of the addresses in my copy of your address book and toss a brick through the window, you'll be able to notice that just fine.

Comment: so appreciated for the thorough explanation

Comment: may I ask it's the same idea also in python?